# Compiling Apache 2.4.10 32bit on Solaris sun sparc 10 64bit

Tags: solaris, apache-httpd

I want to compile Apache 2.4 as 32 bit on Solaris 10 64 bit OS.  I have gcc installed and I have packages of apr, Apr-util, pcre and open SSL with me.  How do I compile it as 32 bit so as to get Apache httpd 32bit Web server?

Answer (score 0):

I've installed Apache on several Solaris boxes, and I'm pretty sure that the typical download of the Apache tar file, extract to a directory, cd to the directory, then

```
./configure
make
```

will create a 32 bit executable, with flags to use 64 bit integers.  After you create the executable, you can just do a

```
file httpd
```

and verify you have a 32 bit binary.  I've noticed most software on Solaris runs a little slower for true 64 bit binaries.

Comment: Thank you, I am. Unable to install Apache 2.4.10 with gcc 3.4.3 which Is there in Solaris 10,but with cc compiler, I am able to install with ease. Can you let me know how to compile and get the cc compiler running on my Solaris machine.

Comment: Hmmm. Sorry I don't have access to a Solaris box any more.